# Issue on Echoing a WordPress Thumbnail by PHP

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am trying to convert my HTML page to a WordPress Theme and so far i am not doing too bad! but I have a problem on loading a Custom post Type thumbnail and adding the required class and style to it. In my HTML I have an image tag like this:

```
<img class="img-circle" src="img/welcom.jpg" data-src="holder.js/140x140" alt="140x140" style="width: 140px; height: 140px;">
```

I trird to echo above tag in my custom WP Query by contaminating the src attribute like `src="'.the_post_thumbnail().'"`  as:

```
echo ' <img class="img-circle" src="'.the_post_thumbnail().'" alt="140x140" style="width: 140px; height: 140px;">';
```

Now I am getting the image on the page but it is not getting any classes and style and the source code looks like 
[image]
Can you please let me know how to fix this?

Comment: get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption that `the_post_thumbnail()` returns the src url is wrong. It returns the whole img element...take a look at the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail)

but essentially you need to pass the class,size and alt as arguments to `the_post_thumbnail()`

```
$size = array(140,140);
$attr = array(
    'class' => "img-circle",
    'alt'   => "140x140"
);
the_post_thumbnail( $size, $attr );
```

Comment: Hi zoranc, thanks for your comment but I am alittile confused here! should I use the $size = array(140,140); and $attr = array(..); inside the Loop or in function.php?

Comment: all of this is used inside the loop... replace your entire echo statement for the image with the code in the answer...since you are specifying the src url, the same image will be used over and over for each post inside the loop (ie welcom.jpg), omitting the 'src' => 'img/welcom.jpg" line would use the set post thumbnail

Comment: if you are working outside of the loop you'd have to use user2092317's recommendation - get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id); –

Comment: Ok I did it but I have still issues here! As I mentioned earlier I am getting the thumbnail from Custom Post Type, so I think hard coding the 'src' => "img/welcom.jpg" is causing some problems as the image is not showing up on the page

Comment: Ok I got it , after removing the 'src' => "img/welcom.jpg", from your code it works perfectly now, thanks

Comment: you can't do like this for a single image...it will solve your problem but with a wrong way..

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code, it will helps you for all the rest of images...

Put this code in your `function.php` file

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) { 
    add_image_size( 'custom-post-thumb', 140, 140,true );
}
```

Now use this in your code:

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>

 <?php the_post_thumbnail('custom-post-thumb', array('class' => 'img-circle')); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks